# Jenkins not installing NPM packages

Tags: jenkins, npm

I am setting up a Jenkins project on windows slave machine
As a build step I am installing node packages
My package.json also have dependencies from git repos.
Node is getting detected by my machine but the npm install command is taking forever to execute and after sometime it gives the following error

`Unhandled rejection Error: premature close
    at PassThrough.onclose (C:\Jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\NodeJS_10.15.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\end-of-stream\index.js:47:67)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)`

Node version
10.15.0

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some eye-candy (formatting) to your question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a dependency (module) is missing the `package.json` or has a syntax or semantic error in the `package.json`.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20824